# PHP File Get Contents wont work

Tags: php, dns, file-get-contents

I have a PHP ad network:
http://rafnet.co.uk/appads/rafappads.php?id=3

it loads a newsletter sign up form as an iframe. this is the URL of that php form:
http://www.rafnet.co.uk/appads/iframes/adnewsletter.html

The form in browser loads fine.

But the php ad network, reads the content of that file into an iframe (300x250).

This was working fine till yesterday i think.

I checked today and the iframes dont load.  I enabled error display in PHP and now it shows this error:

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(http://www.rafnet.co.uk/appads/iframes/adnewsletter.html):
>   failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
>   Temporary failure in name resolution in
>   /home/rafnetco/public_html/appads/rafappads.php on line 585

This is the PHP code:

```
echo file_get_contents($URL);
```

where URL is same as above.

So why is this not working?

Ive not touched the DNS settigns, apache or server or PHP settings recently.

I tried rebooting server and resetting the apache. didnt work

Comment: Have you tried a wget of the url from the command shell of that server? Maybe, the dns really is not working.

Comment: i dont understand why you would ever use file_get_contents on a url of your own domain

Comment: wget http://www.rafnet.co.uk/appads/iframes/adnewsletter.html
--2014-09-08 01:59:40--  http://www.rafnet.co.uk/appads/iframes/adnewsletter.html
Resolving www.rafnet.co.uk... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address `www.rafnet.co.uk'

Comment: Please tell us what is the result of `var_export(dns_get_record('rafnet.co.uk'));` ?

Comment: i added "nameserver 8.8.8.8" to my etc/resolv.conf restarted BIND and apache and hey it works.  I then removed "nameserver 8.8.8.8" from the conf file.  and it still works now.  I dont get it. why?

Comment: i use file get contents as sometimes the URL is one of my one pages BTU sometimes its NOT.  also i tried that var_export it returns an emtpy array

Answer (score 0):

What i did that now makes file_get_contents and wget (from webmin) work is i ran

```
httpd -k restart
```

from command shell on webmin

and then ran

```
httpd -k graceful
```

Now wget works too